# How to create a redirect?

Tags: php

How do I create a php which redirects with use of the URL. I.e. - `Redirect-To.com/Change.php?=Google.com` Then goes to google etc

I'm wanting to create a php page where a user goes to

```
Redirect-To.com/Change.php?=Google.com
or
Redirect-To.com/Change.php?=Youtube.com
or
Redirect-To.com/Change.php?=Yahoo.com
```

Then the visited page redirects to Google or whatever page is after ?=

Comment: Reduce your question title and make it more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what URL shorteners do, except they lookup the destination from a database and probably store some tracking information.

Check out the `header` function that lets you set HTTP headers. You want to set a `302` redirect, which means moved temporarily, and a `Location` header to set the new location.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
header('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily');
header('Location: ' . $newLocation');
```

`301` is another common redirect code, but it means "Moved Permanently" and a lot of browsers will cache that status and not hit your website if the person clicks your link again.

The HTTP spec says you should give the full URL with the redirect, though most browsers will work without it.

You may also want to white list destinations; a user might follow a link to your site and be redirected to a site owned by a a malicious third party. Thinking they were in the confines of your site, they may enter information or perform actions allowing the third party to gain access to their data.

Answer (score -1):

In the URL, values without keys will be ignored, so you should write:

...change.php/?redirect=http://www.google.com

Then you can access the "redirect to" address with `$_GET['redirect']`.

To redirect to a given address, you can use to **Location header** (make sure nothing is sent to the output before calling the function):

`header('Location: ' . $_GET['redirect']);`

You have to start the redirecting URL with "http(s)://" like I wrote above.

If you want to stop the script (as it does not stop immediately after the redirect function), you have to call the `die()` or the `exit()` function.

(If a shorter URL is better for you, the URL can be just ...change.php/?http://www.google.com, then you can access the address with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.)